# Correct asynchronous handling of refreshing jwt token in Angular Interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, interceptor, reactive

I am developing an Angular SPA application with a REST API as backend. I use httponly cookie JWT token and have an interceptor that handles the token refresh cycle when it has expired. The problem is that I have an implementation that relies too much in sequencial coding instead of solving everything with observables.

```
private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):Observable<HttpEvent<any>> | Observable<never> {

if(!this.isRefreshing$.value) {
  this.isRefreshing$.next(true);

  return this.authenticationService.isUserLoggedIn$.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.isRefreshing$.pipe(filter(isRefreshing => !isRefreshing))),
    switchMap(isLoggedIn => {
      if(isLoggedIn){
        return this.authenticationService.refreshToken().pipe(
          switchMap(() => {
              this.isRefreshing$.next(false);

              return next.handle(request);
          }),              
          catchError((error) => {
              if (error.status == '403' || error.status == '400') {
                this.store.dispatch(LoginActions.falseLogout());
              }

              this.isRefreshing$.next(false);
              return throwError(() => error);
          })
        )
      } else {
        return NEVER;
      }
      })
  )
}

return this.isRefreshing$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.authenticationService.isUserLoggedIn$),
  skipWhile(([isRefreshing,isLoggedIn]) => isRefreshing),
  take(1),
  switchMap(([isRefreshing,isLoggedIn]) => {
    if(isLoggedIn) {
      return next.handle(request)
    } else {
      return NEVER;
    }
  })
)}
```

The first section of the **handle401Error** function creates a "refresh cycle" in which the app tries to refresh the token and if succesfull it resends the request to the server. The second section, queues all the subsequent request made to the backend while the token is being refreshed.

The code works as it is, but I know that it can be expressed in a proper "RxJs" way without having to make the if statement at the begining of the function. I have not been able to find the mentioned "RxJs" way... Is it possible to do what I propose? Or is it a good solution the one I already have?